# JNA mapping to pass in/out buffer to winapi function

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I need to enumerate hardlinks to files in a Java app for Windows. I considered using Runtime with `fsutil hardlink list`, but requires administrative privileges.  That led me to WINAPI (ugh).  The Kernel32.dll functions, [FindFirstFileNameW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFileNameW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do this, but I'm having trouble with calling it via the JNA API. FindFirstFileNameW has the specification:

```
HANDLE WINAPI FindFirstFileNameW(
 _In_     LPCWSTR lpFileName,
 _In_     DWORD dwFlags,
 _Inout_  LPDWORD StringLength,
 _Inout_  PWCHAR LinkName
);
```

My JNA mapping:

```
public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary { 
    Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32)Native.loadLibrary("kernel32",Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
    HANDLE FindFirstFileNameW(WString wString, int dwFlags, IntByReference StringLength, ______ LinkName);

    boolean FindNextFileNameW(HANDLE hFindStream, IntByReference StringLength, ______ LinkName);
    boolean FindClose(HANDLE hFindFile);
    int GetLastError();
}
```

Relevant parts of calling function:

```
public String[] getHardLInks(Path path)
{
  Kernel32 lib = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
  IntByReference stringLength = new IntByReference();
  ______ linkName = ______;
  HANDLE hFile = lib.FindFirstFileNameW(new WString(path.toString()), 0, stringLength, linkName);
  String hardlink = //Convert linkName to String
  //Add to array
  // Loop through FindNextFileName
  //Close handle
}
```

The blanks are where I've tried mapping `LinkName`, "a pointer to a buffer to store the first link name found for `lpFileName`", to many things, unsuccessfully.  That includes, strings, char[], byte[], Buffer, Pointer, and Memory, but nothing ever comes back from the call. I believe the rest to be correct from the return values I get from StringLength in testing.  However, `GetLastError` always returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA` (234), which according to the documentation means the buffer is too small, even when I've passed in kilobytes of Memory.

What datatype should I be using and how do I get it back into a String?

Comment: If you've tried a byte buffer array, byte[], how big are you making this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PWCHAR` => `char[]`, although NIO Buffers or memory will also work (just keep in mind that Buffer and memory count in bytes, while the API expects the count in chars).

You also need to initialize the `IntByReference` to the size of your array, otherwise you're telling the API that your buffer is of size zero, and it will obediently fill your buffer with exactly zero characters.

Like most MS API functions of this sort, you can probably pass `null` for the buffer and then it'll write the required buffer size into your length reference.

**EDIT**

One other thing - since you're (correctly) using `W32API_UNICODE_OPTIONS` to initialize your library mapping, `String` will now automatically be mapped to wide character strings (so you don't have to use `WString`), and the `-A/W` function suffix is taken care of automatically, so you can drop the `-W` suffix from your method names.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I totally overlooked the _IN_ part of `StringLength` in the spec.  I must have read the `LinkName` section a dozen times, but skimmed the other once.  Also, thank you for clarifying the mapping since I wasn't sure what I needed there.